# Style mat input on error (adding a mat icon to input field on error)

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, styles, mat-input

I'm trying to style my mat input field on an error by adding an error icon next to the clear field icon like this:

[image]

I can't find any way to add the icon. Thank you for your help in advance.

My HTML:

```
<button
    *ngIf="value"
    matPrefix
    mat-icon-button
    aria-label="Clear"
    (click)="value = ''"
>
    highlight_off
    کلمه جدید 
<input
    class="word-input"
    matInput
    type="text"
    [(ngModel)]="value"
    id="word"
    #wordInput
    required
/>
    error
    کلمه ورودی قبلا وارد شده&zwnj;است
```

CSS:

```
::ng-deep .mat-error {
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 12px;
}

:host ::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-form-field-invalid .mat-form-field-outline- thick,
:host ::ng-deep .mat-form-field.mat-form-field-invalid .mat-form-field-label,
.mat-error {
    color: var(--error) !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look how bootstrap make it in the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/forms/#custom-styles)

then, instead use as class is_invalid you can use .ng-invalid.ng-touched

```
.ng-invalid.ng-touched {
    border-color: #dc3545;
    padding-left: calc(1.5em + .75rem) !important;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='12' height='12' fill='none' stroke='%23dc3545' viewBox='0 0 12 12'%3e%3ccircle cx='6' cy='6' r='4.5'/%3e%3cpath stroke-linejoin='round' d='M5.8 3.6h.4L6 6.5z'/%3e%3ccircle cx='6' cy='8.2' r='.6' fill='%23dc3545' stroke='none'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: leftcalc(.375em + .1875rem) center;
    background-size: calc(.75em + .375rem) calc(.75em + .375rem);
}
```

NOTE: I change the rigth by left in padding and position the image

NOTE2: you can use any svg, e.g.

```
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' fill='%23dc3545' stroke='none' viewBox='0 0 16 16'><path d='M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0zM8 4a.905.905 0 0 0-.9.995l.35 3.507a.552.552 0 0 0 1.1 0l.35-3.507A.905.905 0 0 0 8 4zm.002 6a1 1 0 1 0 0 2 1 1 0 0 0 0-2z'/></svg>");
```

**Update**
If we are working with material angular, we need take account the "floating label"

So, we can use in styles.css

```
input.ng-invalid.ng-touched {
  border-color: #dc3545;
  padding-left: calc(1.5em) !important;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='16' height='16' fill='%23dc3545' stroke='none' viewBox='0 0 16 16'><path d='M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0zM8 4a.905.905 0 0 0-.9.995l.35 3.507a.552.552 0 0 0 1.1 0l.35-3.507A.905.905 0 0 0 8 4zm.002 6a1 1 0 1 0 0 2 1 1 0 0 0 0-2z'/></svg>");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: left center;
  background-size: calc(.75em + .375rem) calc(.75em + .375rem);
}
mat-form-field.mat-mdc-form-field.ng-invalid.ng-touched:not(.mat-focused) .mat-mdc-floating-label.mdc-floating-label:not(.mdc-floating-label--float-above) {
  transform: translate(1.5em,-.15rem);
}
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x67n6s?file=src%2Fstyles.scss)

Comment: thanks for your help. the problem is that I'm using mat form field and mat icons and so on. and ng-invalid and ng-touched don't work on them

Comment: ng-invalid and ng-touched are class that add Angular. I update the answer. If you want to use "icons" just only use `*ngIf="control.touched && control.invalid"`

Comment: thank you very much, it worked perfectly with a little change in styles. thanks again